# Как изменить размер картинки в нужном DIV через CSS для мобильной версии?

Tags: css, css3, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Подскажите пожалуйста, как прописать параметры изображения конкретно для одного типа картинок, которые выводятся у меня как обложка к посту?

Я обычно использовал такую вставку прямо в посту

```
<style>
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) and (max-width : 480px) {
 img {width: 100%;}
}
</style>
```

Но, в CSS файл когда я вставляю код:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    div#single-featured-image-header {
        width: 100%;
    }
```

Рушиться вся верстка.
Как видно по коду, **мне нужны изменения только в div'е : single-featured-image-header**

Что я не так делаю? Буду рад помощи...

Comment: Что значит рушится вся верстка? Я думаю легче было бы понять вашу проблему наблюдая весь код и желательно имея скринклассоТак же не очень понятно почему вы используете id для "одного типа картинок" вместо классов.

Answer (score 0):

Вы похоже забыли закрыть **@media**

**Вместо**

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    div#single-featured-image-header {
        width: 100%;
    }
```

**Надо**

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    div#single-featured-image-header {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Основная проблема в моём случае, что нужно было ставить ".", а не #

```
media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
.single-featured-image-header {
width: 100%;
}
}
```

Спасибо за активность. Я тут первый раз. Теперь буду знать, куда бежать за помощью )